# Undo manager not up to date with NSPersistentDocument

Tags: cocoa, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsundomanager, nspersistentdocument

I have some calculated values in the core data database that I need to update just before saving. Basically I'm numbering some entities in order to ease up the navigation between them.

Currently I'm observing `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and trying to do this numbering there. It would seem that the changes that I make are saved but undo manager still seems to have some modifications. This makes the document look like it has changes (mark on the close button) even though managed object context says that it doesn't have (`hasChanges`). If I undo once, the document looks like it has no changes but in turn, the managed object context does.

Does the undo manager somehow reset itself in the wrong place or am I doing something wrong?

**Update**

The somewhat obfuscated code in which I'm doing this renumbering looks like this:

```
- (void)managedObjectContextWillSave:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // Force the content view controller to save any pending changes.
    [_contentViewController saveChanges];

    NSArray *itemSortDesc = [self sortDescriptorsForSomeItem];
    NSArray *items = [SomeItem findAllObjectsInContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                             andSortBy:itemSortDesc];
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for (SomeItem *i in items)
    {
        i.uid = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:i++];
    }
}
```

The `_contentViewController` contains a text field that will be parsed in to multiple instances of `SomeItem`.

Comment: Would you post the code that handles that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that your numbering affects the undo stack.

I would probably try to handle this in `NSManagedObject willSave` instead of using `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` but I suspect that won't solve your problem.

You could try this:

```
[[self.managedObjectContext undoManager] disableUndoRegistration];

// do the renumbering

[self.managedObjectContext processPendingChanges];
[[self.managedObjectContext undoManager] enableUndoRegistration];
```

I use this to avoid dirtying a brand new document during initialization. I'm not certain it will work correctly for saving, but it might be worth trying.

Comment: This works, thank you. However, for some reason there are one or two empty undo steps after the save but I think this might have something to do with the renumbering since the items' uid is recalculated in any case, even if it does not change. I think I'll consider doing this renumbering instantly after the text field parsing.